# How to find a regression model for data y = 1/x?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I am working on a regression problem with only one feature:
[image: x is a feature and y is the output]

It looks like it could be described as y = 1/x with some transformations. How can I find the model for it? I am using python with scikit-learn.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it is a linear transformation of y = 1/x (i.e. y = a/x + b for some parameters a, b), you can always try fitting y to z1 = 1/x via linear regression. (In other words, you take the inverse of every x datapoint and fit it with y. It should roughly show a straight line, if y = a/x + b.)

Similarly, if the linear transformation is in x (i.e. y = 1/(ax + b)), then you can try fitting z2 = 1/y to x.